# PostgreSql All returning results are "Array"

Tags: php, postgresql

I have this piece of code

```
<?

    $db = pg_connect("host=h port=p dbname=dbn user=usr password=pass");

    if ($db) {
        echo 'Connection attempt succeeded.' . '<br>' . '<br>';
    }
    else{   
        echo 'Connection attempt failed.' . '<br>' . '<br>';   
    }

    $query = "SELECT column1 FROM table";  
    $result = pg_query($db, $query);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) echo $row. '<br>'. '<br>';

    echo pg_dbname($db). '<br>' ;
    echo pg_get_pid($db);
?>
```

The result should be three numeric values. When I run it, all I get are three strings "Array".

Connection attempt succeeded.

```
Array

Array

Array

dbname

pid
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Try `echo array();` You can't simply `echo` arrays.

Comment: use `echo $row['column1']` and don't echo the array use instead print_r/var_dump functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DO:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_all($result)) echo $row['column1']. '<br>'. '<br>';
```

OR debug:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_all($result)) var_dump($row) . '<br>'. '<br>';
```

Comment: Super. I'm glad I can help :)